# Neural Networks, Linear and Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression, logistic-regression

Are Logistic and linear regressions special cases of a neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neural network can be configured to perform logistic regression or linear regression.

In either case, the neural network has exactly one trainable layer (the output layer), and that layer has exactly one neuron (the operator performing the `W * x + b` affine calculation and the activation). They differ in their activation function.

For logistic regression, there is a sigmoid activation function at the output layer, producing a floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0]. You can make a binary decision by applying a threshold of 0.5 to the value.

For linear regression, there is typically no activation function at the output layer, so you get an unbounded floating point number.

In general, you can add hidden layers into your neural network (to add nonlinearity and more learning capacity) and still perform binary classification and regression so long as the output layer activation is configured as written above.

Comment: It is important to note, that only one neuron and only an input and output layer is used to perform either linear or logistic regression.

Comment: @sempersmile: You are right. I was thinking in terms of a generic binary classifier and a generic regression model. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @sempersmile  I was aware that a neural network can be used to perform regressions both logistic and linear. However, I was reluctant to conclude that logistic and linear regression are special cases of neural network. With the only one neuron and only an input and an output layer. I have a better understanding that they are in fact special cases of a neural network